how to expand part of the column to have whole columns even and responsive?
I need to have the headline, text, and button evenly spaced. The image should be next to borders no space between.

<style>
    .blog-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.column .is-fullheight {
  height: 100%;
}
.height-60 {
  height: 60%;
}
</style>
<div class="columns px-6 px-0-mobile is-multiline is-mobile" id="post-previews">
    <div class="column is-full-phone is-half-mobile is-half-tablet 
is-one-third-desktop is-one-quarter-widescreen is-one-quarter-fullhd">
       <div class="is-bordered-light has-text-left is-fullheight">
            <figure class="image is-4by3 mb-3">
                <img class="" src="./img/dummy_640x480_ffffff_cccccc.png">
            </figure>
            
                <div class="px-2 is-family-secondary">
                    <span class="tag is size-6 has-text-weight-bold mr-1 is-primary">Tag</span>
                    <span class="is-primary">July 29, 2023</span>
                </div>
            <div class="blog-item p-2 height-60">
                <a class="our-works-link" href="#">
                    <h4 class="is-size-4 has-text-weight-bold pb-3 is-capitalized">In dapibus augue non sapien. In enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada</h4>
                </a>
                <p class="pb-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet, mauris ac auctor dictum, nisl ligula egestas nulla, et sollicitudin sem purus in lacus. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus ac leo pretium faucibus.</p>
                <div class="has-text-centered">
                    <a class="button is-outlined is-medium our-works-link" href="#">
                        <span class="is-size-8">Read more&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column 
    is-full-phone
    is-half-mobile
    is-half-tablet
    is-one-third-desktop
    is-one-quarter-widescreen
    is-one-quarter-fullhd">
       <div class="is-bordered-light has-text-left is-fullheight">
            <figure class="image is-4by3 mb-3">
                <img class="" src="./img/dummy_640x480_ffffff_cccccc.png">
            </figure>
            
                <div class="px-2 is-family-secondary">
                    <span class="tag is size-6 has-text-weight-bold mr-1 is-primary">tag</span>
                    <span class="is-primary">September 19, 2023</span>
                </div>
            <div class="blog-item p-2 height-60">
                <a class="our-works-link" href="#">
                    <h4 class="is-size-4 has-text-weight-bold pb-3 is-capitalized">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate</h4>
                </a>
                <p class="pb-6">Fusce tellus. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. Curabitur ligula sapien, pulvinar a vestibulum quis, facilisis vel sapien. Praesent in mauris eu tortor porttitor accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas fermentum, sem in pharetra pellentesque, velit turpis volutpat ante, in pharetra metus odio a lectus. Curabitur bibendum justo non orci.
</p>
                <div class="has-text-centered">
                    <a class="button is-outlined is-medium our-works-link" href="#">
                        <span class="is-size-8">Read more&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

this is code of my last try before I had  in whole column and is-fullheight all worked fine but there was space between the picture and border and titles were in different lines due to justify spacing
